# Is this kind of polling acceptable (Angular polls data from Laravel)?

Tags: angular, laravel, polling

I have a forum where I want to display notifications and messages as soon the user gets them. I don't want them to need to refresh to page to see if any notification/message been sent, but I also don't really want to implement 3rd party (like Pusher), that's why I thought I would go with polling.

Basically, if a user is logged in, the polling starts in Angular. Every 10 seconds, a request to Laravel backend is sent, asking if MessageTable has new row, if yes, then the Laravel returns a "true" response, so in angular I display a red dot in the user's profile menu.

When they navigate to the profile, they get the all the messages, including the new ones. 
I don't stop the polling there, in case later they will get more new messages. I unsubscribe from polling only if the user is logged out manually.

Is this acceptable? Should I "clear" something at some point so the website won't crash on client side, or it's fine?

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a suitable solution. As the constant polling would use up resources on the backed by calling every 10 seconds where 99% of the time there is not any new data. Therefore I recommend you to look into websocket implementation using laravel and connect using angular through the websockets. Have a look at this article for more details https://medium.com/dailyjs/real-time-apps-with-typescript-integrating-web-sockets-node-angular-e2b57cbd1ec1.

Comment: This article seems to be about angular + nodejs, not Laravel.